# lambda innerjoin convert error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Hey guys i have the following code,

```
public IList<UserGroupAssignmentModel> GetUsersByGroupName(string name)
{
    var model = _userGroupAssignmentRepository.Table
        .Join(_userGroupsRepository.Table,
            x => x.groupId,
            y => y.Id,
            (x, y) => new { Assignment = x, Group = y })
        .Where(xy => xy.Group.GrpName == name)
        .ToList();

    return model;
}
```

the code is complaining on the return about my model.

```
"Cannot Convert List<anonymousType#7> to Ilist<userGroupAssignmentModel>"
```

Now i think this is because the result of this query is getting all fields from both tables? and trying to store that into a List of UserGroupAssignmentModel's although that is only the 1st table.

whats the correct way to return this result?

UPDATE: UserGroupAssignmentModel contains 4 fields

```
(Id, UserId, groupId, DateAssigned)
```

this model is also used for the _userGroupAssignmentRepository.

_userGroupsRepository is made from UserGroupModel  which has

```
(Id,grpName, GrpDateCreated, GrpIsdeleted,GrpOrderNum)
```

so basically im trying to get a result set from the assignment table based on a link on the group name.  Hope this helps.

EDIT: could you let me know why this question has a downvote? would be nice to know so i can change it possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `UserGroupAssignmentModel` in you query instead of an anonymous class.

Change this

```
(x, y) => new { Assignment = x, Group = y }
```

to this

```
(x, y) => new UserGroupAssignmentModel { Assignment = x, Group = y }
```

or whatever is appropriate for creating a `UserGroupAssignmentModel`.

**EDIT**

or this if you need the values in the query before projection.

```
var model = _userGroupAssignmentRepository.Table
    .Join(_userGroupsRepository.Table,
        x => x.groupId,
        y => y.Id,
        (x, y) => new { Assignment = x, Group = y })
    .Where(xy => xy.Group.GrpName == name)
    .Select(xy => new UserGroupAssignmentModel(/*pass params here*/)
                  {
                      // or set properties here
                  })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: if i do this i lose the assignment and group names, im then forced to use whatever is in that model, however the model is that of my table and such doesnt contain any variable i can use for these 2 references (does that make sense?)

Comment: @StevenSmith Then you need to create a type that *can* store this data, and return a sequence of *that* from this method instead.

Comment: sorry Serv not sure i understand, you mean edit my model(the table) to have 2 fields that can store these values?  Makes no sense, but im guessing its how im looking at it that doesnt make sense

Comment: @StevenSmith Do you mean you need the name for the `Where` part of your query or in the returned values.  If that latter then obviously your model needs to match the results you want.

Comment: @StevenSmith You need to have *some* class that can store the results of your query.  That could be this model, it could be a new class, it could be *anything*, but it has to be *something*.  As it is you're using an anonymous class to store the results, and you cannot use that as your return type.  You need to store your results in something different, and then return *that*.

Comment: @servy yeh i understand using that method 1st proposed this would be needed, possibly use a viewmodel and return that would make sense.

Comment: @juharr OFC!! not sure why i didnt think of a sodding select after the join and clause to filter the results to match by table! nice on mate!

Comment: @StevenSmith I didn't down vote you and I'm not sure why someone did.